# Sqoop import all the table primary and non primary key tables at a time

Tags: sqoop

Can we import tables using sqoop having primary and non primary at a time.Eg i am hvaing 200 primary key tables and 200 non priamry key tables in database .How can we import 400 tables at a time?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jamie's answer:

You can add `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` tag in your `sqoop import-all-tables...` command.

Say you are using 8 mappers (`-m 8`) in your command. Then using above tag tables with primary keys will split as per the number of mappers and tables without primary keys will be loaded using 1 mappers.

*so, overall your efficiency will improve.*

Check 1st point of sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_2) for details.

Comment: I didn't know that option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the flag `--m 1` to the import command of all your tables (both the 200 with primary key and the 200 without it). 
By adding this option, Sqoop will only use one mapper to retrieve all the data from the tables, so your command would look like something like this:

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect your-database --username user --password pwd --m 1
```